# Create JSON correct from an each-loop

Tags: jquery, json, each

I'm trying to create a JSON tree out of an each loop, that get information from several id's on the page. Consider that each id has names like "textHolder1, textHolder2" etc.

```
$('[id^="textHolder"]').each(function(){
TextElementID = this.id;
TextElementContent = $(this).text();
TextElementClass = $(this).attr('class');
TextElementStyle = $(this).attr('style');

json =  JSON.stringify({textElements:{TextElementID:{textContent:TextElementContent,textClass:TextElementClass, textStyle: TextElementStyle}}}, null, 4);
});

alert(json)
```

And I'm trying to get this output in JSON:

```
{
"textElements": {
    "textHolder1": {
        "textContent": "The content",
        "textClass": "theclass",
        "textStyle": "some-styles"
    }
   "textHolder2": {
        "textContent": "The content1",
        "textClass": "theclass2",
        "textStyle": "some-styles2"
    }
}
}
```

How is this done, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build up an object and then `JSON.stringify` the final object.

```
var t = {};
$('[id^="textHolder"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    t[this.id] = {
        textContent: $this.text(),
        textClass: $this.attr('class'),
        textStyle: $this.attr('style')
    };
});

json = JSON.stringify({textElements: t });
```

Comment: @Kim, If it works for you, you can mark it as answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is required to use a `variable value` as `key` in `JSON`, it is needed to be added into `JSON` with `json[variable]` instead of using it in `{}` like `{variable:value}`. Because `{variable:value}` is equals to `{"variable":value}` not `{variableValue:value}`.

So you need to define it like;

```
json={textElements:{}}
//TextElementID is your variable and it should be used as a key like that
json.textElements[TextElementID]={textContent:TextElementContent,textClass:TextElementClass, textStyle: TextElementStyle}

stringifiedJson =  JSON.stringify(json);
```